# Reenable hover with on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container that will show/hide depending on link clicked.

The flow:

- Click menu button and it shows the container for 2 seconds with timer then fades
- Click link *within* container and keeps the container from fading
- Click menu button again and it allows the container to fade again

Oddly, after the last step, if you hover then mouseleave the container it doesn't fade. I've tried. I have a feeling I'm not calling `on()` right.

I've tried using this within the `$('.menu-control').on('click')` to allow the mouseleave again but I assume I need to define it.

```
$('#module-container').on('mouseleave');
```

I've tried a few other ways including wrapping the entire hover within a function, naming it and calling it when the menu button is clicked. No success.

This will be implemented where when a video is playing as the background, the "options" will show after clicking the menu button and fade to stay out of the way. The link within the container will actually stop the video, fade it and the options with stay on the page.

[HERE'S MY VERSION ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/vEbFH/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-enable event handlers like that. When you use `.off()` it removes the specified event handlers from the element. So if you want to re-register the handlers you need to pass the handler reference again to the `.on()` method.

Since you need to use the handler reference multiple times, prefer to write it as a independent function so that it can be referred from multiple places

You need to write it like

```
$('.menu-control').on('click', function() {
    $('#module-container').fadeIn(300);
    window.mtimer = setTimeout(function(){ $('#module-container').fadeOut(300); }, time);
    //The following commented line doesn't work. I want to reallow the mousleave function, defined below (marked as HERE)
    $('#module-container').on('mouseleave', mouseenter);
});

function mouseenter(){
    clearTimeout(window.mtimer); 
}
function mouseleave(){
    window.mtimer = setTimeout(function(){ $('#module-container').fadeOut(300); }, time);
}

var time = 2000;
$('#module-container').on({
    mouseenter: mouseenter,
    //HERE
    mouseleave: mouseleave
});

$('.stopme').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#module-container').show().off('mouseleave');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```